# Caching for faster recompression of folder given edit/add/delete

Tags: compression

## Summary

Let's say I have a large number of files in a folder that I want to compress/zip before I send to a server. After I've zipped them together, I realize I want to add/remove/modify a file. Can going through the entire compression process from scratch be avoided?

## Details

I imagine there might be some way to cache part of the compression process (whether it is `.zip`, `.gz` or `.bzip2`), to make the compression incremental, even if it results in sub-optimal compression. For example, consider the naive dictionary encoding compression algorithm. I imagine it should be possible to use the encoding dictionary on a single file without re-processing all the files. I also imagine that the loss in compression provided by this caching mechanism would grow as more files are added/removed/edited.

## Similar Questions

There are two questions related to this problem:

1. A [C implementation, which implies it's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34258649/1079075)
2. A [C# related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19454303/1079075), which implies it's possible by zipping individual files first?
3. A [PHP implementation, which implies it isn't possible without a special file-system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23968149/1079075)
4. A [Java-specific adjacent question, which implies it's semi-possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41860241/1079075)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulting the man page of `zip`, there are several relevant commands:

## Update

> ```
> -u
> --update
> ```
>
> Replace (update) an existing entry in the zip archive only if it has
>   been modified more recently than the version already in the zip
>   archive. For example:
>
> ```
>     zip -u stuff *
> ```
>
> will add any new files in the current directory, and update any files
>   which have been modified since the zip archive stuff.zip was last
>   created/modified (note that zip will not try to pack stuff.zip into
>   itself when you do this).
>
> Note that the -u option with no input file arguments acts like the -f
>   (freshen) option.

## Delete

> ```
> -d
> --delete
> ```
>
> Remove (delete) entries from a zip archive.  For example:
>
> ```
>     zip -d foo foo/tom/junk foo/harry/\* \*.o
> ```
>
> will remove the entry `foo/tom/junk`, all of the files that start with
>   `foo/harry/`, and all of the files that end with .o (in any path).
>   Note that shell pathname expansion has  been  inhibited with
>   backslashes, so that zip can see the asterisks, enabling zip to match
>   on the contents of the zip archive instead of the contents of the
>   current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The entries in a zip file are all compressed individually. You can select and copy just the compressed entries you want from any zip file to make a new zip file, and you can add new entries to a zip file.

There is no need for any caching.

As an example, the zip command does this.